# Fetched results in a section crash

Tags: core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsindexpath

I am using core data to fetch an entity. I only want those results to show up in the second section of my tableview and something else show up in another section... My app isnt crashing, but the fetched data is not showing up in the table view... I also am sure I am fetching the data correctly.

Here is some code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

if (indexPath.section==0){
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell.textLabel.text = _team.teamName;
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.textLabel.text = _team.headCoach;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}

if (indexPath.section ==1) {
    Player *p = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath: indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = p.firstName;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = p.team.teamName;
}       

return cell;

}
```

Comment: The if/then for your FRC is within the if/then of the first section.

Comment: Ok I edited it back but now I am getting that same error again index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Comment: See my edits below.  Problem is with using indexPath with FRC's objectAtIndexPath method

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me out... All the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues, first you should only have one section, so you don't need to access the sections properties. So try this

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    switch(section){
        case 0:
            return 7;
        case 1:
            return [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

secondly, you have an issue with where you are using the following code:

```
Player *p =[_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath: indexPath];
```

It is causing the problem because you are calling it for both sections and your fetch has only one section.

To fix the crash, either wrap it with a conditional that checks for the correct indexPath.section or place it inside your switch/case statement for section 1.  You can do something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    if (indexPath.section==0){
        switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell.textLabel.text = _team.teamName;
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.textLabel.text = _team.headCoach;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }else{
        Player *p = [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = p.firstName;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = p.team.teamName;
    }       

    return cell;

}
```

Good luck

T

Comment: Yes I know the crash is happening there... What is the best way to fix it?

Comment: I am a little un sure on how to do that... Could you provide some sample code?

Comment: Yes I have tried doing that but I still get the error -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

Comment: you have an issue with your implementation of numberOfRowsInSection method.  see edit.

Comment: Ok I appreciate the help. I change my code around, see the edit in my question... The app doesn't crash anymore but the players are no longer showing in the section.

Comment: Glad to help.  Core Data is tough to get your head around, but once you do, it is really powerful